# Index numpy 3d-array with 1d array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array of shape `(i, j, k)`. I have an array of length `i` which contains indices in `k`. I would like to index the array to get a shape `(i, j)`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape(2, 3, 4)

# array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#         [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#         [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
#
#       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

indices = np.array([1, 3])

# I want to mask `arr` using `indices`
# Desired output is equivalent to
# np.stack((arr[0, :, 1], arr[1, :, 3]))
# array([[ 1,  5,  9],
#        [15, 19, 23]])
```

I tried reshaping the `indices` array to be able to broadcast with `arr` but this raises an `IndexError`.

```py
arr[indices[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :]]
# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

I also tried creating a 3D mask and applying it to `arr`. This seems closer to the correct answer to me but I still end up with an `IndexError`.

```py
mask = np.stack((np.arange(arr.shape[0]), indices), axis=1)
arr[mask.reshape(2, 1, 2)]
# IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Comment: You can use advanced indexing: `arr[np.arange(len(arr)), :, indices]`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: Thanks @Psidom - this works. do you want to add this as an answer? happy to accept it

Comment: Looks like @ryangooch already posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand in your example, you can simply pass `indices` as your second dimension slice, and a `range` of length corresponding to your indices for the zeroth dimension slice, like this:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(2 * 3 * 4).reshape(2, 3, 4)

indices = np.array([1, 3])

print(arr[range(len(indices)), :, indices])
# array([[ 1,  5,  9],
#        [15, 19, 23]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
sub = arr[[0,1], :, [1,3]]
```

Output:

```
>>> sub
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [15, 19, 23]])
```

A more dynamic version [by @Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427063/index-numpy-3d-array-with-1d-array-of-indices#comment124493737_70427063):

```
>>> sub = arr[np.arange(len(arr)), :, [1,3]]
array([[ 1,  5,  9],
       [15, 19, 23]])
```